# Botão reset no formulário

Tags: cakephp

Quero resetar todos os campos de um formulário usando framework CakePHP.

O que acontece é o seguinte, o botão cadastrar só fica habilitado se o usuário marcar o checkbox para aceitar.

Se ele clicar no botão limpar, quero que deixe os campos do tipo texto vazios e reset também o `radio` e `checkbox`.

Da forma que estou fazendo só funciona para resetar o tipo texto, mas quero resetar todos os tipos de campos do formulário. Vamos a parte dele.

```
echo $this->Form->create('users');

echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>'login'));

echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>'senha'));

//checkbox para abilitar o cadastro

echo $this->Form->input('aceitar', array('label'=>'aceito realizar cadastro', 'name'=>'aceitar', 'onclick'=>'cadastrar.disabled!=checked'));

//botao cadastrar

echo $this->Form->submit('cadastrar', array('label'=>'Cadastrar', 'name'=>'cadastrar', 'onclick'=>'disabled=true'));

//reset

//da forma abaixo só desabilita o botão cadastrar e o checkbox continua marcado.

echo $this->Form->button('limpar', array('label'=>'limpar', 'onclick'=>'cadastrar.disabled=true'));

//ou desmarca o checkbox e o botão fica disponível.

echo $this->Form->button('limpar', array('label'=>'limpar', 'onclick'=>'aceitar.checked=false'));
```

As duas formas acima não me corresponde.

Eu quero desmarcar o `checkbox` e desabilitar o botão cadastrar, já tentei usar dois `onclick` no botão reset, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma função em `javascript` para que limpe os campos

```
$(function(){
    $('#aceitar').on('click', function(){
       $('#enviar').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#limpar').on('click', function(){
       $('#aceitar').prop('checked', false); 
       $('#enviar').prop('disabled', true);
       $('#nome').val(''); 

    });
});
```

Exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf17dqep/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar JavaScript puro para resolver seu problema por ser muito simples.

Exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode adicionar um input do tipo `reset`, ele irá resetar o formulario para seus valores padrões, exemplo:

Form:

```html
 <form name="myform" method="POST">
  <input type="text" size="25" value="">
  <input type="text" size="25" value="Valor default">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar"> 
  <input type="reset" value="Resetar!">

</form>
```

Comment: Faço isso, mas usando framework. Você fez o que eu faço, mas em html. Não sanou minha questão!

Comment: O código faz exatamente o que você quer, porem da maneira adequada,  a diferença e que não utiliza javascript como a resposta que você marcou como correta, sua justificativa não é valida.

Comment: @AndréNascimento entendo que a resposta do David não lhe satisfaça, mas o problema é que no titulo e na pergunta você só pede pra resetar o formulário e o David respondeu exatamente isto, mas ao ler o teu código vejo que vai além de resetar, você quer resetar e desabilitar em determinadas circunstancias, no entanto você não descreveu isto na pergunta e claro que a maioria não poderia entender o objetivo, recomendo que quando for formular uma pergunta siga as dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ...

Comment: @AndréNascimento Talvez se você tive-se usado no minimo a tag `javascript` na pergunta o David e os demais poderiam ter deduzido isto, mas como você não o fez, acho errado criticar a resposta do David, ela esta perfeitamente cabível ao que está descrito, por isto sempre tente ser o mais claro para evitar respostas invalidas. Uma boa noite! Espero que leve tudo isto como dicas construtivas :)

Comment: @DavidSchrammel +1 pelo seu esforço, pois a resposta responde no momento o que está descrito na pergunta.